# How to join different dataframe with specific criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, mysql-python

In my MySQL database `stocks`, I have 3 different tables. **I want to join all of those tables to display the EXACT format that I want to see**. Should I join in mysql first, or should I first extract each table as a dataframe and then join with pandas? How should it be done? I don't know the code also.

This is how I want to display: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fc3mll0q3vefm3q/expected%20output%20sample.csv?dl=0

[image]

Because this is just an example format, it only shows two tickers. The expected one should include all of the tickers from my data.

So each ticker is a row that contains all of the specific columns from my tables.

Additional info:

- I only need the **most recent 8 quarters** for quarterly and **5 years for yearly** to be displayed
- The exact date for different tickers for quarterly data may differ. If done by hand, the most recent eight quarters can be easily copied and pasted into the respective columns, but **I have no idea how to do it with a computer to determine which quarter it belongs to and show it in the same column as my example output**. (I use the terms q1 through q8 simply as column names to display. So, if my most recent data is May 30, q8 is not necessarily the final quarter of the second year.
- If the most recent quarter or year for one ticker is not available (as in "ADUS" in the example), but it is available for other tickers such as "BA" in the example, simply leave that one blank.

1st table `company_info`: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g95tkczviu84pnz/company_info.csv?dl=0 contains company info data:

[image]

2nd table `income_statement_q`: https://www.dropbox.com/s/znf3ljlz4y24x7u/income_statement_q.csv?dl=0 contains quarterly data:

[image]

3rd table `income_statement_y`: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpq79p8lbayqrzn/income_statement_y.csv?dl=0 contains yearly data:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
# Convert as datetime64 if necessary
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])  # quarterly
df3['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['date'])  # yearly

# Realign date according period: 2022-06-30 -> 2022-12-31 for yearly
df2['date'] += pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)
df3['date'] += pd.offsets.YearEnd(0)

# Get end dates
qmax = df2['date'].max()
ymax = df3['date'].max()

# Create date range (8 periods for Q, 5 periods for Y)
qdti = pd.date_range( qmax - pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(7), qmax, freq='Q')
ydti = pd.date_range( ymax - pd.offsets.YearEnd(4), ymax, freq='Y')

# Filter and reshape dataframes
qdf = (df2[df2['date'].isin(qdti)]
                      .assign(date=lambda x: x['date'].dt.to_period('Q').astype(str))
                      .pivot(index='ticker', columns='date', values='netIncome'))

ydf = (df3[df3['date'].isin(ydti)]
                      .assign(date=lambda x: x['date'].dt.to_period('Y').astype(str))
                      .pivot(index='ticker', columns='date', values='netIncome'))

# Create the expected dataframe
out = pd.concat([df1.set_index('ticker'), qdf, ydf], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  ticker                                  industry                  sector     pe    roe     shares  ...       2022Q4          2018          2019          2020          2021          2022
0   ADUS          Health Care Providers & Services             Health Care  38.06   7.56   16110400  ...          NaN  1.737700e+07  2.581100e+07  3.313300e+07  4.512600e+07           NaN
1     BA                       Aerospace & Defense             Industrials    NaN   0.00  598240000  ... -663000000.0  1.046000e+10 -6.360000e+08 -1.194100e+10 -4.290000e+09 -5.053000e+09
2    CAH          Health Care Providers & Services             Health Care    NaN   0.00  257639000  ... -130000000.0  2.590000e+08  1.365000e+09 -3.691000e+09  6.120000e+08 -9.320000e+08
3   CVRX          Health Care Equipment & Supplies             Health Care   0.26 -32.50   20633700  ...  -10536000.0           NaN           NaN           NaN -4.307800e+07 -4.142800e+07
4   IMCR                             Biotechnology             Health Care    NaN -22.30   47905000  ...          NaN -7.163000e+07 -1.039310e+08 -7.409300e+07 -1.315230e+08           NaN
5   NVEC  Semiconductors & Semiconductor Equipment  Information Technology  20.09  28.10    4830800  ...    4231324.0  1.391267e+07  1.450794e+07  1.452664e+07  1.169438e+07  1.450750e+07
6   PEPG                             Biotechnology             Health Care    NaN -36.80   23631900  ...          NaN           NaN           NaN -1.889000e+06 -2.728100e+07           NaN
7   VRDN                             Biotechnology             Health Care    NaN -36.80   40248200  ...          NaN -2.210300e+07 -2.877300e+07 -1.279150e+08 -5.501300e+07           NaN

[8 rows x 20 columns]
```

Comment: The response is useful. If I use the exact code, this is what I get: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uv1iik6m0u23gxp/output.csv?dl=0. First question: Is it possible to move the column names [industry, sector,..., 2022Q4... 2022] down one row so that they are on the same row as the column name 'ticker'? because there is now a blank row after the column name 'ticker'. Second question: if I want to add more columns to display, such as revenue or data from another database, do I just use the same code logic? I didn't show in question just to make it look shorter and easier to read.

Comment: 3rd question: Also, 'BA' displays 9 quarters while 'ADUS' displays 8 quarters because it lacks the most recent quarter in sync with 'BA'. The same idea applies to yearly data. Is it possible to show only 8 quarters and 5 years, regardless of whether they are missing or not? Instead of adding another?

Comment: the output is actually wrong. For yearly data, CAH, NVEC are showing NAN for yearly data. But there's data in my files.

Comment: @saga. I updated my answer and fixed some errors. I also removed MultiIndex from the output result.

Comment: I used values=['revenue,'operatingIncome,'netIncome'] to replicate your code and already added revenue, operatingIncome, in addition to netIncome. Now I have to add eps as well. I've already updated the expected output (highlighted sections) and added the 4th and 5th earnings tables. 'fiscalDateEnding' will be used. I'm at a loss for how to proceed because my source data (5th table earnings_y) for ex., NVEC has both 2022-03-31 and 2022-12-31. CAH has both 2022-06-30 & 2022-12-31. The dates were changed and having duplicates when I used pd.offsets(). So how should we go about it?

Comment: You should not change your question as you go when an answer solves the original question. Now you add 2 others files. And what after that?

Comment: I used your qdf & ydf concepts to pivot a new df for earnings qtr & yr. When I run the code and reach the new df for earnings yr line, it says duplicate error becuz my source file, NVEC, contains both 2022-03-31 & 2022-12-31. CAH has both the 2022-06-30 & 2022-12-31 dates. When I manipulate the dates with pd.offsets(), they became 2 rows with the same dates 2022-12-31 for both NVEC & CAH. In this case, I know it's up to me how to handle it. But my question is, is it necessary to use pd.offsets() to manipulate the dates first, so that we can later assign which quarter it belongs to?

Comment: It's necessary to align dates to choose the right ones.